# How to check if url from xpath exists?

Tags: scrapy

I have two functions in Scrapy

```
def parse_attr(self, response):
      for resource in response.xpath(''):
        item = Item()
        item['Name'] = response.xpath('').extract()
        item['Title'] = response.xpath('').extract()
        item['Contact'] = response.xpath('').extract()
        item['Gold'] = response.xpath('').extract() 
        company_page = response.urljoin(resource.xpath('/div/@href').extract_first()) 

        if company_page:
            request = scrapy.Request(company_page, callback = self.company_data)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request
        else:
            yield item

    def company_data(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['Products'] = response.xpath('').extract()
        yield item
```

`parse_attr` calls `company_data` when it extracts `@href` from page and it passes it to `company_page`, however, this href does not always exists. How can i check if href exists, and if not, stop scrapy from moving to other function?

Above code does not satisfy this condition because company_page is always true.

What I want is scrapy to stop if there is no href, and finish its job just with items it already has. If href is found, then I want scrapy to move to other function and extract additional item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`response.urljoin()` will always return something (the request's base URL), even if the argument is empty. Therefore your variable will always contain a value and consequently evaluate as `True`.

You need to do the URL joining inside your conditional. For example:

```
company_page = resource.xpath('/div/@href').extract_first()

if company_page:
    company_page = response.urljoin(company_page)
    request = scrapy.Request(company_page, callback = self.company_data)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request
else:
    yield item
```